# Converting WAV file bytes to speech recognition-compatible format

Tags: python, audio, speech-recognition, wav, pydub

I've been pounding my head against a wall for three days on a Python automation pipeline that takes the binary byte array of .WAV email attachments (e.g. b'RIFFm\xc1\x00\x00WAVEfmt [...]') a phone system automatically pushes, push it through some text-to-speech API like `speech_recognition` or some future offline Sphinx/Kaldi implementation, and send a transcript back. Ideally, this would all be handled in memory without needing to create files on disk since that seems superfluous but I'm trying to figure out anything that Pythonically moves from the audio data I have to a transcript I can send and I don't mind a little file cleanup.

The problem I'm running into is the .WAV file attachments I manually downloaded for testing and binary data I'm working with through the email API aren't playing nice with the `wave` dependency, with `wave.open('ipsum.wav')` giving an `Error: unknown format: 49` and work with the `speech_recognition` library ends with that `wave` unknown format error translating into a `ValueError: Audio file could not be read as PCM WAV, AIFF/AIFF-C, or Native FLAC; check if file is corrupted or in another format`.

Manually converting the local files I have into .wavs using an online file conversion tool seems to fix the issue in a way `speech_recognition` is willing to work with and I've managed to get a working transcript doing this (the transcript was too short for the file but that's a separate chunking issue). So the problem seems to be that `wave` isn't happy with how the files the phone system sends me are formatted/encoded/compressed and the solution sits somewhere in replicating how that web conversion tool encoded those test files.

I've been messing around with `pydub`'s `.export()` function to try forcing it to convert to something `wave` likes (`pydub` has managed to play those files) but it seems to have taken me in a circle and I wind up back where I started with the error traceback discussed above. The ideal solution probably lies in some tool that manipulates the byte array of email attachments in memory but, again, I'm open to any Pythonic suggestions.

I might change up the text-to-speech framework I use from Google's somewhere down the line but the code for I've got so far for my basic implementation:

```
from exchangelib import Message
import io
import pydub
import speech_recognition as sr

r = sr.Recognizer()
def speech_to_text(Message):
    for attachment in Message.attachments:
        if attachment.content_type == 'audio/x-wav':
            content = attachment.content # Store attachment's binary data as a variable
            bytes = io.BytesIO(content) # Encode IO as bytes
            f= pydub.AudioSegment.from_file(bytes).export(attachment.name[:-4] +'.wav', format='wav') # Use bytes to create pydub's AudioSegment object
                                                                                                        # and export it as desired format
            with sr.AudioFile(f) as source: # Feed converted file into speech_recognition's AudioFile
                audio = r.record(source)
                transcript = r.recognize_google(audio)
                return transcript
```

If you have any good resources or courses that can teach me about audio file conversion in a Pythonic fashion (I've been struggling with a major gap between very practical resources that assume your audio processing working perfectly and extremely theory-heavy discussion), I'm more than happy to hear them as well.

Comment: As I understand it, the primary problem here is getting the WAV file from your system to Python. Can you share any example of such a troublesome WAV file? It will make fixing the problem much easier for us.

Comment: Cool, ping me when you have the data. If sharing it in the open isn't an option, feel free to use my email. Cheers!

Comment: @LukaszTracewski dropbox.com/s/asamm4tad3myyal/msg0000%20%282%29.WAV?dl=0 The file is coming from Grandstream's phone system. I'm not sure what the specific model is but it looks like Dropbox has some good info on the codec.

Comment: Thanks! Did my answer solve your problem?

Comment: @LukaszTracewski I'm still working on it but I have a pretty good idea of how to fix it. I'm currently attacking the FFMPEG angle.

Comment: `ffmpeg` can certainly convert the audio to a PCM format. However, you asked about Python solution and that's what I provided. If it doesn't solve your problem, would be good to hear feedback. If it does, you should accept the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Standard library wave module supports only `PCM` encoding as evidenced by [this code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/515fce4fc4bb0d2db97b17df275cf90640017f56/Lib/wave.py#L259):

```py
if wFormatTag == WAVE_FORMAT_PCM:
    try:
        ...
    else:
raise Error('unknown format: %r' % (wFormatTag,))
```

What you are dealing with is `8,000 Hz GSM 06.10`, or, more commonly, `GSM`. More about different coding schemes you can read on the [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WAV#Comparison_of_coding_schemes).

Evidence from [soxi](http://sox.sourceforge.net/soxi.html):

```
soxi msg0000\ \(2\).WAV 

Input File     : 'msg0000 (2).WAV'
Channels       : 1
Sample Rate    : 8000
Precision      : 16-bit
Duration       : 00:00:07.96 = 63680 samples ~ 597 CDDA sectors
File Size      : 13.0k
Bit Rate       : 13.1k
Sample Encoding: GSM
```

#### Solution

Use any library that supports GSM encoding. [soundfile](https://pypi.org/project/SoundFile/) is a great choice; many popular audio modules uses it underneath.

```
import soundfile as sf

sf.read('msg0000 (2).WAV')
```

Output:

```
(array([0.00024414, 0.        , 0.        , ..., 0.00048828, 0.00048828,
        0.00024414]),
 8000)
```